# Facebook Send Message Dialog Without Redirecting

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm looking to add some functionality to my website to allow people to send messages to their friends via the facebook send dialog. The issue is that it requires a redirect_uri parameter which the window redirects to when the user clicks send/cancel. I was wondering if there is any way to automatically close the send message popup when the user clicks send/cancel without redirecting  (like the unsupported facebook.com/sharer.php does)? The code I have so far is:

```
        FB.init({appId: '*****'});
        FB.ui({
            method: 'send',
            name: *****,
            picture: *****,
            link: *****,
            display: 'popup'
        });
```